# MySQL show records month wise

Tags: mysql, datetime, sum

I have some records in my Database table.

User passes the start and the end date and then expects an output. If a user passes the start and end date for same month then it should show only one record, but if the end date is extended one or more month then it should displays month wise record.

For now I am able to collect total data while following this query.

```
SELECT m.data_date_time
     , SUM(m.kwh) total_kwh
     , m.cust_id Customer_ID
     , m.msn
  FROM mdc_meters_data m 
 WHERE m.data_date_time >= '2020-04-01 00:00:00' 
   AND m.data_date_time <= '2020-05-31 00:00:00'
```

**Output**

```
Data_Date_Time      == total_kwh == Customer_ID == MSN
2020-04-01 11:44:13 || 95585     || 37010114707 || 7898985212
```

**Expected Output**

As the month end date is `05` so it should show two records like below

```
Data_Date_Time      == total_kwh == Customer_ID == MSN
2020-04-01 11:44:13 || 50000     || 37010114707 || 7898985212
2020-05-01 10:25:05 || 45585     || 37010114707 || 7898985212
```

I have tried to put `GroupBy data_date_time` but it doesn't helped me out.

How can I do this ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Without a GROUP BY clause, and with the SUM() aggregate in the SELECT list, the query will not return more than one row.  (If sql_mode includes ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY then MySQL will return an error for this query, behavior more consistent with the standard and most other RDBMS Oracle, SQL Server, Teradata, et al.  A MySQL specific extension allows the query to return rows, but the values returned for non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT list (cust_id, msn) are *indeterminate*. The values will be returned from some row in the collapsed group, but no guarantee which row.)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT m.`data_date_time` AS 'Data_Date_Time', SUM(m.`kwh`) AS total_kwh, m.`cust_id` AS 'Customer_ID', m.`msn` AS MSN, date_format(data_date_time, "%Y-%m") as monYear
FROM `mdc_meters_data` m WHERE m.`data_date_time >=
2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND m.`data_date_time`<='2020-05-31 00:00:00' group by monYear

Hope it will help you for getting idea

Comment: The query is not returning correct result. when I tried to pass date time from `m.data_date_time >='2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND m.data_date_time<='2020-05-31 00:00:00'` the sum is `401320` for `2020-04-01` and `84220` for `2020-05-31` but when I pass the date time `m.data_date_time >='2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND m.data_date_time<='2020-04-30 00:00:00'` the sum is `370570`. Why is this ?

Comment: would you please put your table

Answer (score 0):

please check this answer

```
    SELECT m.`data_date_time` AS 'Data_Date_Time', SUM(m.`kwh`) AS total_kwh, m.`cust_id` AS 'Customer_ID', m.`msn` AS MSN 
FROM table AS r JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(m.`data_date_time`) AS data_date_time
        FROM table AS t
        GROUP BY YEAR(m.`data_date_time`), MONTH(t.data_date_time)
    ) AS x USING (data_date_time)

`mdc_meters_data` m WHERE m.`data_date_time`>='2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND m.`data_date_time`<='2020-05-31 00:00:00'
```

Comment: it's giving me error. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'table AS r JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `GROUP BY` the correct manner.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('m.`data_date_time`, '%Y-%m') AS Data_Date_Time, 
       SUM(m.`kwh`) AS total_kwh, 
       m.`cust_id` AS Customer_ID,
       m.`msn` AS MSN 
FROM `mdc_meters_data` m 
WHERE m.`data_date_time`>='2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND m.`data_date_time`<='2020-05-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY Customer_ID, Data_Date_Time, MSN
```

Now the problem with the above query is that you don't need to group your results by `MSN`

One workaround is to use `any_value` function around your nonaggregated `MSN` columns in the select list. This will just pick any `MSN` value from the matching list and make sure you will still have only 2 entries shown in the results.

```
SELECT any_value(DATE_FORMAT('m.`data_date_time`, '%Y-%m')) AS Data_Date_Time, 
       SUM(m.`kwh`) AS total_kwh, 
       m.`cust_id` AS Customer_ID,
       any_value(m.`msn`)
FROM `mdc_meters_data` m 
WHERE m.`data_date_time`>='2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND m.`data_date_time`<='2020-05-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY Customer_ID, Data_Date_Time
```

Also, note how the 31st of May has been included in your query by giving by extending the range to the time 23:59:59.

Comment: `Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function 'any_value'` it's giving me this error

Comment: Answer edited. You should have realized how to make it work anyway.

Comment: now it's giving me `FUNCTION mdc_db.any_value does not exist`

Comment: `any_value`  is a standard mysql function. If your server cannot find it, you have a problem in your server. https://riptutorial.com/mysql/example/26731/any-value--